# Remove empty lines in txt export from [excel] [vba]

Tags: excel, vba

Not the best at VBA but I will give some context to help explain this probably stupid question.

The place I work for has a terrible system so we tend to do things our own way and use the system as little as possible.
We wanted to be able to take direct debits from customers as and when we need to and to do this we needed to create a 'BACS Standard 18' file to upload to the bank in order to collect the direct debits. The file requires there to be specific information about the transaction and it has to be displayed in a very specific way in notepad(txt).

I managed to create an Excel file that our finance team can use in order to create the file but when the file is created the typing cursor is always found to be a couple of lines under the exported text.

I need the text to be exported and the typing cursor to be at the end of the last line of the text, or a least not underneath. If it is under it, the bank will see that as a blank line and not accept the file. The number of lines in the file will always be different as well.
I have attached an example of the file in a screenshot. The highlighted part is what the file should include but as you can see the typing cursor is two lines lower.
Can someone please help with this and explain where I have gone wrong.
Thank you.
[exportedfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MtCI.png)

Below is the [vba] used to build the file and export the data from excel to notepad:

```
Sub Build_BACS()
LastRow = (Worksheets("Input").Range("Q2"))

'Header
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "=""VOL1""&Home!D5&""                               ""&Home!D2&""                                ""&""1"""
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "=""HDR1A""&Home!D2&""S""&""         ""&Home!D5&""00010001       ""&Home!D8&"" ""&Home!E8&"" 000000                    """
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "=""HDR2F02000""&Home!B11&""                                   00                            """
ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Value = "=""UHL1 ""&Home!D8&""999999    000000001 DAILY  001                                        """

'Middle
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value = "=CONCAT(Input!C2,Input!D2,Input!K2,Input!G2,Input!H2,""    "",Input!L2,Input!M2,""  "",Input!N2,Input!O2)"
On Error Resume Next
Range("A5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:A" & LastRow + 4), Type:=xlFillDefault


'Footer
If Sheets("Home").Range("A2").Value = "TMR" Or Sheets("Home").Range("A2").Value = "TMRF" Or Sheets("Home").Range("A2").Value = "TMREA" Then
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & LastRow + 5).Value = "=TEXT(Home!C2,""000000"")&TEXT(Home!B2,""00000000"")&""099""&TEXT(Home!C2,""000000"")&TEXT(Home!B2,""00000000"")&""    ""&TEXT(Input!P2,""00000000000"")&""The Mailing Room  CONTRA            TMR               """
ElseIf Sheets("Home").Range("A2").Value = "DPS" Then
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & LastRow + 5).Value = "=TEXT(Home!C2,""000000"")&TEXT(Home!B2,""00000000"")&""099""&TEXT(Home!C2,""000000"")&TEXT(Home!B2,""00000000"")&""    ""&TEXT(Input!P2,""00000000000"")&""DPS               CONTRA            TMR               """
End If
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 6).Value = "=""EOF1""&MID(A2,5,76)"
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 7).Value = "=""EOF2""&MID(A3,5,76)"
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 8).Value = "=""UTL1""&TEXT(Input!P2,""0000000000000"")&TEXT(Input!P2,""0000000000000"")&""0000001""&TEXT(Input!Q2,""0000000"")&""                                    """


'Export
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim output As String
For Each r In Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 8).Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        output = output & c.Value
    Next c
    output = output & vbNewLine
Next r
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ([Indirect("Home!B13")]) & ".txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output

Close

InputBox "Noice." & Chr(13) & "Your file is just in here", "File Path", "Z:\My Documents\Orrin Lesiw\Direct Debit\Convert File"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding ; to Print suppressed the vbNewLine. However `output = output & vbNewLine` will always add a newline so either add to front for lines 2 onwards like

```vb
Sub out2()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim output As String
    For Each r In Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 8).Rows
       
        If r.Row > 1 Then output = output & vbNewLine
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & c.Value
        Next c
        
    Next r
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ([Indirect("Home!B13")]) & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output;
    
    Close
End Sub
```

or transpose the range into an array and use `Join`

```vb
       ' Export
       Dim ar
       ar = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 8))
       Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ([Indirect("Home!B13")]) & ".txt" For Output As #1
       
       Print #1, Join(ar, vbNewLine);
       Close
```